# Ejecutar comando junto con archivo en un archivo .bat

Tags: cmd

estoy intentando crear un archivo .bat para poder hacer arrancar el sistema gulp que tengo.

Lo que hago hasta ahora es abrir una consola de DOS, ir a la ruta 'D:\mi_proyecto\gulp\bin' luego ejecutar el comando 'gulp.js serve' y con esto arranca.

Lo quiero automatizar en un .bat y para ello hice un archivo con estas instrucciones:

```
@echo off
D:\mi_proyecto\gulp\bin\gulp.js serve
exit
```

Pero no me funciona. Probé también poniendo comillas en las órdenes:

```
@echo off
D:\mi_proyecto\gulp\bin\"gulp.js serve"
exit
```

Pero tampoco. Por favor alguien me podría dar una mano con esto? Gracias.

Comment: por otro lado, si quitas el `@echo off`, probablemente verías algun error que te indicaría cual puede ser el problema

Comment: Haciendo eso me devuelve "gulp.js" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: El problema es que intentas ejecutar un archivo javascript, lo que no es posible desde msdos. Prueba con `D:\mi_proyecto\gulp\bin\gulp serve` (sin poner la extension) o `D:\mi_proyecto\gulp\bin\gulp.bat serve`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la forma. El contenido del archivo .bat debe ser este:

```
@echo off
d:
cd D:\mi_proyecto\gulp\bin\
node .\gulp.js serve
```

Lo que hace primero es ir al disco D con la línea d: (ya que el archivo y la orden que deseo ejecutar están en mi disco D).
Luego, la tercer línea, hace que la ruta se posicione en la carpeta donde está el archivo que quiero ejecutar. Finalmente, en la cuarta línea, node es el comando que me permite ejecutar código Javascript (.js) y luego el comando serve es el que utilizo para arrancar el servidor.

Comment: Hola Ucha, deberías añadir una pequeña descripción de cómo funciona y por qué es diferente de las otras respuestas que te han proporcionado. Lee [answer] para más información sobre cómo mejorar tus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Recomiendo que hagas lo siguiente:

```
@echo off
cd D:\mi_proyecto\gulp\bin\
gulp.js serve
exit
```

Con el `cd` te estás colocando en ese directorio.

Otra opción si quieres todo en una linea sería algo así:

```
@echo off
cd D:\mi_proyecto\gulp\bin\ && gulp.js serve
exit
```

Con el `&&` te permite realizar varias ordenes en la misma ejecución

Personalmente recomiendo la primera opción, ya que la segunda alguna vez me ha causado problemas, aunque no tengo muy claro el motivo.

Comment: con ambas opciones me responde "gulp.js" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Answer (score 0):

separa las instrucciones de cambiar de unidad con la de cambio de directorio

```
@echo off
d:
cd \mi_proyecto\gulp\bin
gulp.js serve
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo OFF
MODE con: cols=100 lines=30
@echo OFF
title servidor
COLOR 02
cd D:\mi_proyecto\gulp\bin\
call npm server.js
```

Tambien puedes remplazar estos comando

```
call npm start
start http://localhost:3000/ && call npm start
```

La otra opcion es que que te vayas a entorno de variable y configures tu proyecto haci se ejecutara desde cmd con una sola letra o numero que le pongas a tu archivo.bat

Comment: Si necesitas ampliar tu respuesta puedes utilizar el enlace de `editar` que se muestra al final de tu respuesta. No crees nuevas respuestas.